# VBA Excel accessing index with named range

Tags: excel, vba

Quick example in VBA Excel:

I have defined two named ranges with the same dimensions: `MyNamedRangeA` and `MyNamedRangeB`.
These are column vectors.

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in .range(MyNamedRangeA)
   Call MyFunction(cell)
Next cell
```

I want `MyFunction` to hide the row of `cell`if another cell with the same index in `MyNamedRangeB` has the string value `x`

```
Sub MyFunction(cell As Range)
index = GetIndex(cell)
If .range(MyNamedRangeB)(index) = "x" Then
   cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

I would like to get help with completing this program.

Specifically, I need to find out a way to perform the "GetIndex" operation, i.e. to provide the row index of the cell

Comment: What does `GetIndex` do?

Comment: Let's say that `cell` is the second cell of `MyNamedRangeA`. Then `GetIndex(cell)` would return the integer `2`.

Comment: What help do you need ? What did you try ? With which results ?

Comment: I need help with creating a program with the purpose described as above. Or finishing the example above by giving a definition of `GetIndex()`

Comment: You don't need a `GetIndex` if you enumerate cells using index. See the example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dim i as Integer
dim myRangeA as Range
dim myRangeB as Range

dim MyNamedRangeA as String
dim MyNamedRangeB as String

With MySheetReference    
    set myRangeA = .Range(MyNamedRangeA)
    set myRangeB = .Range(MyNamedRangeB)


    For i = 1 to myRangeA.Cells.Count
      If myRangeB.Cells(i).Value = "x" Then
         myRangeA.Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      End If
    Next
End With
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is just a problem with the way you are referencing named ranges and easy to fix.

These need to be referenced as Range("RangeNameAsString") so for your first function you will get..

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in Range("MyNamedRangeA")
   Call MyFunction(cell)
Next cell
```

I've done a quick test and if you make appropriate changes this seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that cells in worksheet have 2 index, row and column.
You can check

```
 If .Range(MyNamedRangeB).Cells(cell.Row-.Range(MyNamedRangeA).Row+1, cell.Column-.Range(MyNamedRange).Column-1).Value = "x" Then ...
```

That way you will check cell value in MyNamedRangeB which is same number of rows down and columns left from beginning of named range as cell in MyNamedRangeA.

Comment: Should it be: `If .Range(MyNamedRangeB).Cells(cell.Row-.Range(MyNamedRangeA).Row+1, cell.Column-.Range(MyNamedRangeA).Column-1).Value = "x" Then ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bit different logic for that without additional function and using different kind of loop. Here if part of the code you could try to incorporate to your solution:

```
'...your code here
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To .Range(MyNamedRangeA).Cells.Count
    If .Range(MyNamedRangeA).Cells(i).Value = .Range(MyNamedRangeB).Cells(i).Value Then
        .Range(MyNamedRangeA).Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
'...rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in Range("MyNamedRangeA")
   Call MyFunction(cell)
Next cell

Sub MyFunction(cell As Range)
  index = Range("MyNamedRangeA").Cells(1,1).row - cell.row
  If range(MyNamedRangeB)(index,1) = "x" Then
     cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If
End Sub
```